# I'm having trouble displaying images to a canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a routine that will take a series of images, calculated from numpy arrays and processed through PIL, and make a UI that will display those images to a 2nd screen at a defined frame rate using tkinter. Primarily, I've been trying to create a button in tkinter.ttk that will run a command to place the images on a canvas one after another. I have been running into some difficulty, though, with the button commands.

I wrote the following:

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

img_list = []
for j in range(5): #randomly generated series of 1920x1080 images
    randarray = np.random.rand(1080,1920)
    img_list.append(Image.fromarray(np.array(256*randarray,dtype = np.uint8)))

root = tk.Tk()
w,h = root.winfo_screenwidth(),root.winfo_screenheight()#get window information
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w+1920, h))
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,width = w,height = h)
canvas.configure(background = 'black')
canvas.place(x = w) #place canvas on second screen
killbutton = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text = 'kill root',
    command = root.destroy)
killbutton.place(x = 0, y = 0)
def display(imagelist = [], *args):
    for images in imagelist:
        tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(images, master = root)
        canvas.create_image(960,540, image = tkimage)
        time.sleep(3)#display 1 image every 3 seconds
        print('check')
displaybutton = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text = 'display frames',
    command = display(img_list))
displaybutton.place(x=200,y=0)
root.mainloop()
```

From what I can tell with the check run in the function, the display function runs when I run the code and thereafter the root appears on my screen. Nothing happens when I press the button. I'm quite frankly baffled and don't know how where to go from here. I would very much appreciate some advice.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of the callback or handler function. Do like ```command = lambda: display(img_list)```.